# How often does the spell Sleet Storm require concentration checks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

The 4th level spell Sleet Storm says

> If a creature is concentrating in the spell’s area, the creature must make a successful Constitution saving throw against your spell save DC or lose concentration.

How often is this condition checked? Each round? Each turn?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## When they start their turn in its area

*[Sleet Storm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sleet-storm)* specifies (my emphasis):

> **If a creature starts its turn in the spell's area and is concentrating on a spell**, the creature must make a successful Constitution saving throw against your spell save DC or lose concentration.

Just walking in and out won't be a problem. It's only an issue that forces a concentration save if they start their turn in the spell's area.

Older PHB printings don't have this text, but the special edition box set and all printings thereafter should include the [V2.0 errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf)  from November, 2018. This particular change appears as [new] in the linked document.

Comment: This must have been added as an errata since my PHB was published. Makes sense tho

Comment: @Destruktor Just checked, and yup - that was it. My PHB also has it without that language.

Comment: @Destruktor Yeah, looks like that was one of the new errata in the November 2018 document ("version 2.0").

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I believe that errata was included in the special edition books, no?

Comment: @G.Moylan Yes, that's correct.  The 2.0 errata matches the special edition box set and future printings of the PHB.

Comment: @G.Moylan Thanks for the clarification!